# Alpaca form add button to text field

Tags: forms, button, field

I'm trying to implement a custom field with one text field and a few buttons. See attached screenshot. I tried adding a button but the button is placed under the text input bar, not what I wanted. Any idea?

[Screen shot of what the custom field should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fX0l.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should post some of the relevant html code... and probably some css.

The behaviour you are describing is either caused because you are using html incorrectly or because some css is not being applied as you expect.

Comment: The behavior I described is in the text field sample. Example 15 on this page:http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/fields/text.html